How to change `CD` into `PD` and `ChristoffelCDPD` in xCoba
I'm working with xAct`xCoba`, with the setting up as
<< xAct`xCoba`

$PrePrint = ScreenDollarIndices; (*Was needed for nice printouts*)
$CVVerbose = False;
DefManifold[M4, 4, {b, d, f, h, i, j, k, l, m, p, q, s}];
DefChart[sch, M4, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {r[], \[Theta][], \[CurlyPhi][], t[]},
   ChartColor -> Green];
DefMetric[-1, metricg[-i, -j], CD, PrintAs -> "g", 
 SymbolOfCovD -> {";", "D"}]


DefConstantSymbol[M];
MetricInBasis[metricg, -sch, 
 DiagonalMatrix[{1/(1 - 2 M/r[]), 1 - 2 M/r[], r[]^2, 
   r[]^2 Sin[\[Theta][]]^2}]]
MetricCompute[metricg, sch, All]

Now I want to get the expression of covariant derivative of a tensor, like
DefTensor[v[i], M4]
CD[-{i, sch}]@v[{j, sch}]
%// ComponentArray // TraceBasisDummy // ToValues

I want to convert the above CD[-{i, sch}]@v[{j, sch}] into PDsch and ChristoffelCDPDsch. In fact, CD[-{i, sch}]@v[{j, sch}] is equal to PDsch[-{i, sch}]@v[{j, sch}] +  ChristoffelCDPDsch[{j, sch}, -{i, sch}, -{k, sch}] v[{k, sch}]. So that I could evaluate CD[-{i, sch}]@v[{j, sch}] explicitly like
exp = PDsch[-{i, sch}]@v[{j, sch}] + 
  ChristoffelCDPDsch[{j, sch}, -{i, sch}, -{k, sch}] v[{k, sch}]
exp // ComponentArray // TraceBasisDummy // ToValues


So my question is: how to convert an expression of CD into PD and ChristoffelCDPD in xCoba`?
